# opencv2 imshow doesn't update after cascade detectMultiScale

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCV noob here, I followed some online articles and made some changes on my guess and came up with this code:

```
import cv2, time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(1)
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")

def detect(image):
    faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(image)
.
    for _face in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (_face[0], _face[1]), (_face[0]+_face[2], _face[1]+_face[3]), (255,255,255))

def repeat():
    ret, image = cap.read()
    detect(image)
    cv2.imshow("w1", image)


while True:
    repeat()
```

problem is if I use `detect` method, the window doesn't update image feed, without seeing the feeds I cannot continue working on drawing the rectangle on faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

throw in a :

```
cv2.waitKey(5)
```

after the

```
cv2.imshow()
```

your window just does not get updated else

Comment: the whole message-pump needed for updating the window is hidden in there. calling it 'waitKey' might be a misnomer

Comment: I am curious why waitKey is not needed if `detect()` not not called?